# Which type of resource (cid) can be in HTML email?

Tags: html, css, email, mime-types, content-type

I'd like to know which kind of resource (image? video? other?) can be embedded in HTML email using cid, like this:

```
<img id="Immagine_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01CCB130.010345C0">
```

Do you think it's a good strategy for saving HTML as a whole is to search and replace cids with base64 encoded data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most mail clients rip out all but the most basic HTML. MS Outlook, which is used by about 40% of mail users, uses the MS Word engine (barf) to render emails - so none of this embedding will ever work there.

Here's a good guide:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

In general: while it may be possible in SOME cases to embed rich content in email, it's more likely not to work with a wide enough audience to be worth the effort.